# Java convert 4 bytes to single variable

Tags: java, arrays, byte

What I am trying to do is place 4 bytes that are currently in an array into a single byte variable.  For example:

```
public myMethod()
{
   byte[] data = {(byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x4C, (byte) 0xD6, (byte) 0x00 };
   writeData(testMethod((byte)0x4C, data));
}

public byte[] testMethod(byte location, byte[] data)
{
    byte[] response = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x21, location, data);
    return response;
}
```

This obviously dose not work because you cannot cast byte to byte[].

Any ideas?

EDIT:
There is some confusion as to what I am asking.  What I am looking for is

```
data = (byte) 0x034CD600;
```

In the "testMethod".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `byte[]` big enough to store the elements from `data`.

```
public byte[] testMethod(byte location, byte[] data)
{
    byte[] response = new byte[3 + data.length];
    response[0] = (byte) 0x00;
    response[1] = (byte) 0x21;
    response[2] = location;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        response[3 + i] = data[i];
    }
    return response;
}
```

Use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) if speed is important. I find the above more understandable.

The notation

```
byte[] response = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x21, location, date);
```

is, as you said, illegal. The `{...}` initializer only accepts variables or literals of type `byte`.

Comment: That works if I am trying to place the data at separate indexes.  I need to place them all in the same index.

Comment: @Talls I don't understand. You cannot fit 4 bytes (32 bits) into 1 byte (8 bits).

Comment: You are correct.  I misunderstood the context of the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```
private static final byte[] HEADER = new byte[] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x21 };

public static byte[] testMethod(byte location, byte[] data) {
    byte[] response = Arrays.copyOf(HEADER, HEADER.length + data.length + 1);
    response[HEADER.length] = location;
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, response, HEADER.length + 1, data.length);
    return response;
}
```

or if you are using `ByteBuffer`s

```
public static ByteBuffer testMethodBB(ByteBuffer bb, byte location, byte[] data) {
    if(bb.remaining() < HEADER.length + 1 + data.length) {
        bb.put(HEADER);
        bb.put(location);
        bb.put(data);
        bb.flip();
        return bb;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Buffer overflow!");
}
```

Comment: +1 I like the `ByteBuffer` solution. You can always return the backing array too.